# Selectable text on <a> tags with fixed width

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a link as a button, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xm27qepj/)

HTML:

```
<a class="contact" href="mailto:dummy@test.dummy">E.mail us</a>
```

CSS:

```
.contact{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

The issue I am having is that I need to allow user to copy text from this link. However as this has width set and I need this fixed width(text length can change, but width will remain same). User can only select text from one or another side, but not directly inside the block(if that makes sense).

Any ideas on solution for this with still having this size link? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean "copy text from this link" ?

Comment: in this particular case I talk about this text: "E.mail us". This text is a text of a link as hyperlink is attached to it. Hope this clears things up. :)

Comment: Why would someone need to select the text of a "button"? Your request (since this is a link for clicking) isn't really logical.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Your button already has the with you specified, and you can already copy the text in the button. What is your issue?

Comment: Hover text and then try to select text. It is selectable only if you try to select from outside blackbox and towards inside.

Comment: Related: [How to select (& copy) only a part of a linked text?](http://superuser.com/q/583795) and [How do I select middle part of a hyper link?](http://superuser.com/q/482266)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `<div>` outside your `<a>` tag

```
<div class="contact">
<a href="mailto:dummy@test.dummy">E.mail us</a>
</div>
```

You can change text-color if you don't want it blue.

**EDIT:**

If you want to mantain the links size you can always add some padding to `<a>` tag to cover the entire size of the parent container.

Comment: paddings as mentioned don't fit as I need the same size block while text content can be changed from time to time, which changes width of element with paddings as well. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="contact">
   <a href="mailto:dummy@test.dummy">E.mail us</a>
</div>
```

and in order to make the link appear white again:

```
.contact a {
color: white;
}
```

However, you should not that if you want the whole black box to be "clickable" it won't be possible to achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

what did you mean copy text from this link?

define you css class outside of `<a>` tag with add `<div>`
here is the HTML code

```
<div class="contact">
   <a href="mailto:dummy@test.dummy">E.mail us</a>
</div>
```

you can add another css class for link

```
a{
    display:block;
    font-family:arial;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#06C;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;

}
```

here is online tool to create beautiful css
http://www.css3maker.com/

Comment: "E.mail us" - this text should be selectable, but when you hover it, click and drag - it is not selectable. Does that make sense?